# What are the edit and new actions doing in this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :regions
  has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end


class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :appartments

  has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end


class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :country
  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => {
      :thumb=> "100x100>",
      :small  => "300x300>",
      :large => "600x600>"
  } 
end
```

Can some explain to me what the edit and new method/action is of the region controller, to store the asset(image)?

Comment: If you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets` inside of your Region model, than the action will be the same as for create/edit region. So the actual storing of assets will be made when region is saved (in regions_controller#create & regions_controller#update actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could do it by building your form in a certain way. It should work for both the new and update actions.

```
<%= form_for @region do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :assets, @region.assets.build do |fa| %>
    <%= fa.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What this does is to first create the form for the @region instance. And since you have the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets` you can use the `fields_for` method to work with the associations. The symbol `:assets` tells it which association to read from, but since you want to add a new image and not work with the existing, you can add the second argument which is a single new Asset instance created by the `build` method.

And then finally you can add the `file_field` to actually upload the file.

If you build your form this way you should not have to alter the action code inside your controller at all.

Edit:

And here is how the `new` and `create` actions could look like to make the view work:

```
def new
  @region = Region.new
  # Add respond_to or respond_with if you want
end

def create
  @region = Region.new(params[:region])
  if @region.save
    render :action => :show
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

Comment: i can't get this working. can you tell me how my new and create method

Comment: post the @region.assets.build in the form, but i got an error message  "undefined method `assets'